# Question on sequence of $\;L^2\;$ integrable functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits, lp-spaces

> Let $\;f_n\;$ be a sequence of functions such that $\;f_n \in
>  L^2((l_{-}^{f_n},l_{+}^{f_n}),\mathbb R^m)\;$ where $\;-\infty\le
>  l_{-}^{f_n} \lt  l_{+}^{f_n} \le +\infty\;$. If I knew $\;\lim_{n \to
>  \infty} l_{\pm}^{f_n}=l_{\pm}^{\infty}\;$, would it be possible to
>   claim that $\;f_n \in L^2((l_{-}^{\infty},l_{-}^{\infty}),\mathbb
>  R^m)\;$?

**My approach:**

Since $\;f_n \in L^2((l_{-}^{f_n},l_{+}^{f_n}),\mathbb R^m)\;$, it holds $\; \int_{l_{-}^{f_n}}^{l_{+}^{f_n}} {f_n(x)}^2 \;dx \lt \infty\;$. If I let $\;n\to \infty\;$, I get confused because in this case (I believe) I get $\; \int_{l_{-}^{\infty}}^{l_{+}^{\infty}} \lim {f_n(x)}^2 \;dx\;$. But all I want is $\; \int_{l_{-}^{\infty}}^{l_{+}^{\infty}} {f_n(x)}^2 \;dx\;$.

What am I missing? Is my initial question wrong? Any help would be valuable!

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend your functions $f_n$ with $0$ on $(l_-^\infty,l_+^\infty)\setminus (l_-^{f_n},l_+^{f_n})$.

Then

$$
 \; \int_{l_-^\infty}^{l_+^\infty} {f_n(x)}^2 \;dx 
 \leq
 \; \int_{\min(l_-^\infty,l_-^{f_n})}^{\max(l_+^\infty,l_+^{f_n})} {f_n(x)}^2 \;dx 
=
  \; \int_{l_{-}^{f_n}}^{l_{+}^{f_n}} {f_n(x)}^2 \;dx \lt \infty\;.
  $$

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your quick answer! I don't understand completely why $\;(l_-^{f_n},l_+^{f_n}) \subset (l_-^\infty,l_+^\infty)\;$

Comment: that does not have to be the case. But the inequality still holds, because the integral can only get bigger when the domain gets bigger

Comment: I guess I must be super silly but I can't see why the domain gets bigger...I believe it gets smaller. What am I missing?

Comment: it doesnt have to get bigger. it can also get smaller

Comment: But if it gets smaller how does the inequality hold?

Comment: I edited. If it gets smaller, the inequality becomes an equality and holds because we extended with zero

Comment: Oooh, I think I got it now. Since $\;\lim_{n \to
 \infty} l_{\pm}^{f_n}=l_{\pm}^{\infty}\;$ it follows $\;(l_-^{f_n},l_+^{f_n}) \subseteq (l_-^\infty,l_+^\infty)\;$ and by extension with 0 , I deduse the inequality. Am I right??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61365/discussion-between-supinf-and-kaithkolesidou).